# Can I use ATL in a native C++ service?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, atl

If I use the native windows API calls(like StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(), etc) instead of ATL service(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74y2334x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to install, uninstall or control my service and still use certain ATL functions, will it screw everything up?

Answer (score 5):

It is safe to use ATL in a service.  The one caveat to watch out for is that if the service hosts a COM server that is consumed by other processes, make sure to call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` before calling `CoRegisterClassObject()` on Win2003+ or else `CoRegisterClassObject()` will fail.  The order of the calls does not matter on earlier OS versions.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm assuming you're working with native code, not dotnet.  Is that the case?)

Stuff like ATL, MFC are wrappers around the native Win32 calls.  There shouldn't be problems
using the native and wrappers in the same app.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should be fine to control your service via Native WinAPI calls, and still use ATL for other stuff. I have seen this happening in production code before. For example, WinAPI calls controlled the service, but some crypto functions in `<atlenc.h>` were used.

That said, I can't guarantee that it would be safe to mix *all* of the ATL functions. Your best bet is to read the full documentation for an ATL function before committing to using it.